# Fields inaccurate in Blazor for each loops

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a for-each loop in my component, and in the loop, a component I made is rendered. It is passed an object, then the component initializes its own fields in the `OnInitialized` overridden function.

The problem I have is that when the array for the for-each loop changes, the component's values that are not inputted parameters get mixed up.

You can see this bug live here: https://blazor-field-glitch.azurewebsites.net.

You can see the full source code here: https://github.com/AskYous/FieldSharingGlitch

Here's the code that produces this issue:

```html
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var color in filteredColors)
    {
        <div class="col-4">
            <ColorCard color="color" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
@code {
    private string filter { get; set; }
    private List<Color> colors = Color.SampleData;
    private List<Color> filteredColors
    {
        get => colors.Where(c => c.SatisfiesQuery(filter)).ToList();
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("focusFilter");
    }
}
```

And for the ColorCard component:

```html
<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img" src="@imageUrl" style="height: 400px;" />
    <div class="card-body">
        <small style="color:gray">Is the image accurate after you filter ?</small>
        <h2>@color.Name</h2>
        <p>@color.Description</p>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public Color color { get; set; }
    private string imageUrl { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        imageUrl = color.ImgUrl; // does not stay. keeps changing.
    }
}
```

The `imageUrl` field is what's causing the issue. If you filter for "Yellow," it will use the `imageUrl` for red. It's not keeping track of the `imageUrl` field.

Here's a gif demo:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. It was to use `@key`, similar to React's `key` attribute. See here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-key-to-control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components